# Best way to inject css into admin_head in plugins?

Tags: plugins, css

I'm looking for the best way to inject CSS into WordPress' Admin CP.

Currently, I'm using the `admin_head` action hook and in this hook, I'm using `dirname( __FILE__ )` to retrieve the directory for the stylesheets. However, `dirname()` does retrieve the server's path. **Is this the recommended way or is there some sort of WordPress function to get a *URI* path rather than a *directory* path?**

```
    public function admin_head()
    {
        // Let's include the Control Panel CSS
        $url = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/css/cpanel.css';
        $ie = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/css/cpanel-ie.css';

        // Inject our cPanel styelsheet and add a conditionaly for Internet Explorer
        //      (fixes bugs on my home browser)
        $head = <<<HEAD
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$url}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$ie}" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
HEAD;

        echo $head; 

        foreach( self::$classes as $class => $obj )
        {
            if ( method_exists( $obj, 'admin_head' ) )
            {
                $obj->admin_head();
            }
        }
    }
```

-Zack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url). It's perfect and engineered to link to files in plugin folders.

PS also [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) might make sense in the mix.

Comment: Hmmm. `wp_enqueue_style`: can that be used to inject css based upon browser? Or would the general idea I have (only with `plugins_url`) be the best way to do that?

Comment: @Zack I vaguely remember there is `$is_IE` global var, never used that myself. See [`vars.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/vars.php).

Answer (score 6):

There's another way to add conditional comments, using WP's API:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    'my-ie-style',
     get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/cpanel-ie.css'
);

global $wp_styles;
$wp_styles->add_data( 'my-ie-style', 'conditional', 'IE' );
```

`

Comment: Wow! Never knew this. For those who interested here is [chunk of code that handles this in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php#L63).

Comment: +1. Great example of the kind of hidden API functions that make me keep loving WordPress!

Comment: I'm drawn to this snippet. I really like it. I'll look into it further after I've tested @mfields 's answer.

Comment: That is definitely neat! Have really had no need to dig into the Dependencies class before. @filosofo While I agree that this seems to be a more direct approach, I try to avoid touching global objects as much as possible in extensions and use hooks wherever possible.

Answer (score 3):

I originally didn't think that this was possible, but then I did some digging and came up with the following solution which works for me on WordPress 3.1. The tricky part was getting the conditional tags for IE in there. There's a filter for it!

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
*/
class My_Plugin {
    function My_Plugin() {
        add_action( 'wp_print_styles', array( &$this, 'css_public' ) );
        add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', array( &$this, 'ie_conditional_comments' ), 10, 2 );
    }
    function css_public() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin', plugins_url( '/my.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-ie', plugins_url( '/my-ie.css', __FILE__ ), array( 'my-plugin' ), '1.0' );
    }
    function ie_conditional_comments( $tag, $handle ) {
        if ( 'my-plugin-ie' == $handle ) {
            $tag = '<!--[if IE]>' . $tag . '<![endif]-->';
        }
        return $tag;
    }
}
$my_plugin = new My_Plugin();
```

Best wishes,
-Mike

Comment: Nice snippet! But for admin it would probably be easier to (not) queue depending on global var for IE, since there is no static caching scenario to worry about.

Comment: This looks like something I need, I'm playing with it right now and will come back to mark an answer as 'The Answer' ;)